# Unexpected Token Illegal Multiline String javascript+ php

Tags: php, javascript, google-chrome

I'm passing a **multiline string** from PHP to Javascript and I am getting a `Unexpected Token Illegal` error

I think the fact that its multi-line is causing the error but I'm not sure. I don't even need the string to be multi-line but it is stored as multiline in the database (and there's nothing I can do to change that).

This is what I tried to remove the multi-line characters but it didn't work

```
$str= str_replace(array("",json_decode('\u000A'),json_decode('\u000B'),
                 json_decode('\u000C'),json_decode('\u000D'),
                 json_decode('\u0085'),json_decode('\u2028'),
                 json_decode('\u2029')),"",$str);
```

Basically I attempted to remove all types of new line characters from the string

I've checked the other questions but they don't seem to solve the issue

I either need a fix on the PHP or the javascript side. Using Chrome

Thanks

Comment: Using `json_decode` for this is a horrible idea! PHP supports escape sequences, too...

Comment: Actually the function `json_encode` which you hopefully use to create your JSON string, already does correctly escape all quotes, backslashes, multi-byte characters, etc. So it should not be an issue. Obviously some bit of information is missing here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those strings are valid JSON. They would be if you had quotes inside.. i.e. `json_decode('"\u000A"')`

Comment: Found this in a stackoverflow question. Can you give me an example of an escape sequence?